# Where the gold at?

Tags: tinker-island

I've recently gained access to a few buildings and items that have gold costs. Unfortunately I haven't seen any gold in game yet. Where can I expect to find gold? Is it only found through exploration and foraging, or is there some gold per hour building like the fishing spot/lumber camp?

I've explored everything through the meadow right now and am still at a level 1 bonfire.

Comment: Love the title... I immediately thought of Blazing Saddle's line "Where all da white woman at?" (or am I too old that nobody else knows that movie?)

Comment: @TimS. Perhaps they just have a drinking problem *spills drink everywhere*

Comment: The only way I got gold up to now is by exploring locations, namely ones which I already visited. I am not 100% sure since I didn't play much though.

Comment: @GodEmperorDune always love the _Airplane_ references :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While exploring the Cavern zone, I unlocked the "furnace" building. The furnace is a labor building that produces metal (the resource that looks like gold bars) very slowly.

As mentioned in the comments by Crowley Astray, metal is also a random reward for re-exploring the completed zones when a part item is not found.